# How to make strings from my database show up in my localisation .po file in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, internationalization, django-i18n

in one of my python projects, I'm looping through a list of countries which is stored in my SQLite database:

```
            {% if europe %}
                {% for country in europe %}
                            <figcaption>{{ country.Name_fr }}</figcaption>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
```

I am using localization so I have a locale folder with .po files with which I handle the different translations. However I would like to have the database strings (from {{ country.name_fr }}) show up in these .po files. This means I would have to include a translate tag but if I try it, it shows an error. This:

```
<figcaption>{% translate {{ country.Name_fr }} %}</figcaption>
```

leads to this:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /

Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [`translate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#translate-template-tag) template tag documentation states

> It’s not possible to mix a template variable inside a string within {%
> translate %}. If your translations require strings with variables
> (placeholders), use {% blocktranslate %} instead.

So you could use [`blocktranslate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktranslate-template-tag)

```
{% blocktranslate %}
    {{ country.Name_fr}}
{% endblocktranslate %}
```

---

Even simpler for your use case would be to just pass variable to translate

> The {% translate %} template tag translates either a constant string
> (enclosed in single or double quotes) or variable content

```
{% translate  country.Name_fr %}
```

Comment: This does not actually translate the variable though. If I set this in the template, "python managy.py makemessages" does not recognize the string, does not write it into the po file and therefore doesn't translate it. Do I maybe have to translate it in the model?

Comment: If you have additional strings that need to be translated you have to add them manually as makemessages will not find anything that is database related

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for. I thought it was necessary for the string to be added to the po file by makemessages but adding the strings from the database by hand and including the translate tag in the template worked fine. Thank you!